# How to print a superCF with pycassa

Tags: cassandra, pycassa

The following code fails (ValueError: too many values to unpack
, under pycassaShell)
Is there some way to pretty print the supercolumns?

```
cf = pycassa.ColumnFamily(pool, 'Super1')
res = cf.get_range()
for key, col in res:
    print '\n\n', key, ':'
    for k, c in col:
        print k, '=>', c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
cf = pycassa.ColumnFamily(pool, 'Super1')
res = cf.get_range()
for key, col in res:
    print '\n\n', key, ':'
    for i in col.keys():
        print i, '=>', col[i]
```